# postgres STRING_AGG() returns duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, average

I have seen some similar posts, requesting advice for getting distinct results from the query. This can be solved with a subquery, but the column I am aggregating `image_name` is unique `image_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE`. I don't believe that should be necersarry.

This is the data in the spot_images table

```
spotdk=# select * from spot_images;
 id | user_id | spot_id |              image_name              
----+---------+---------+--------------------------------------
  1 |       1 |       1 | 81198013-e8f8-4baa-aece-6fbda15a0498
  2 |       1 |       1 | 21b78e4e-f2e4-4d66-961f-83e5c28d69c5
  3 |       1 |       1 | 59834585-8c49-4cdf-95e4-38c437acb3c1
  4 |       1 |       1 | 0a42c962-2445-4b3b-97a6-325d344fda4a
(4 rows)
```

```sql
SELECT Round(Avg(ratings.rating), 2) AS rating, 
       spots.*, 
       String_agg(spot_images.image_name, ',') AS imageNames
FROM   spots 
       FULL OUTER JOIN ratings 
                    ON ratings.spot_id = spots.id 
       INNER JOIN spot_images 
               ON spot_images.spot_id = spots.id 
WHERE  spots.id = 1 
GROUP  BY spots.id;
```

This is the result of the images row:

```
81198013-e8f8-4baa-aece-6fbda15a0498,
21b78e4e-f2e4-4d66-961f-83e5c28d69c5,
59834585-8c49-4cdf-95e4-38c437acb3c1,
0a42c962-2445-4b3b-97a6-325d344fda4a,
81198013-e8f8-4baa-aece-6fbda15a0498,
21b78e4e-f2e4-4d66-961f-83e5c28d69c5,
59834585-8c49-4cdf-95e4-38c437acb3c1,
0a42c962-2445-4b3b-97a6-325d344fda4a,
81198013-e8f8-4baa-aece-6fbda15a0498,
21b78e4e-f2e4-4d66-961f-83e5c28d69c5,
59834585-8c49-4cdf-95e4-38c437acb3c1,
0a42c962-2445-4b3b-97a6-325d344fda4a
```

Not with linebreaks, I added them for visibility.

What should I do to retrieve the image_name's one time each?

Comment: The duplicates are returned because of the FULL OUTER join. If you joined only spots and spot_images then you would not get duplicates.

Comment: @forpas do you just mean a standalone `join` with no outer/inner/left/right qualifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates, use `DISTINCT`:

```
   String_agg(distinct spot_images.image_name, ',') AS imageNames
```

Comment: That was quick and easy - why is that required? Why does it aggregate over 11 records when there only exists 4?

Comment: @JonasGrønbek . . . Aggregation functions aggregate over the entire set, including duplicate values.  If you want `distinct`, you need to be explicit.

Comment: Why does the entire set have more than 4 image_names?

Comment: @JonasGrønbek . . . There are either duplicates in your data or you don't have the right `JOIN` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, there are several rows in `ratings` that match the given `spot`, *and* several rows in `spot_images` that match the given `sport` as well. As a results, rows are getting duplicated.

One option to avoid that is to aggregate in subqueries:

```
SELECT r.avg_raging
       s.*, 
       si.image_names
FROM   spots s
       FULL OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT spot_id, Round(Avg(ratings.rating), 2) avg_rating
           FROM ratings
           GROUP BY spot_id
       ) r ON r.spot_id = s.id
       INNER JOIN (
           SELECT spot_id, string_agg(spot_images.image_name, ',') image_names
           FROM spot_images
           GROUP BY spot_id
       ) si ON si.spot_id = s.id 
WHERE  s.id = 1
```

This actually *could* be more efficient that outer aggregation.

Note: it is hard to tell without seeing your data, but I am unsure that you really need a `FULL JOIN` here. A `LEFT JOIN` might actually be what you want.